# Is there a way to create CSS image styles?

Tags: media

**Is there a way to assign css to image styles?**

I don't see any drop down for custom...

Would be nice to add img-responsive style to ALL images on the site...

Is there a module that can do that? Shouldn't it be native functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is considered theming and is done mainly in the theme's template.php file.

There is a guide available here: [Add bootstrap image css class to pictures](https://www.drupal.org/node/2169157)

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_image_style(&$vars) {
        $vars['attributes']['class'][] = 'img-responsive'; // http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images
}
?>
```